# Pandas: bar plot with multiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame with a `TIMESTAMP` column (not the index), and the timestamp format is as follows:

```
2015-03-31 22:56:45.510
```

I also have columns called `CLASS` and `AXLES`. I would like to compute the count of records **for each month** separately for each unique value of `AXLES` (`AXLES` can take an integer value between 3-12).

I came up with a combination of `resample` and `groupby`:

```
resamp = dfWIM.set_index('TIMESTAMP').groupby('AXLES').resample('M', how='count').CLASS
```

This seems to give me a multiIndex dataframe object, as shown below.

```
In [72]: resamp

Out [72]:

AXLES  TIMESTAMP 
3      2014-07-31      5517
       2014-08-31     31553
       2014-09-30     42816
       2014-10-31     49308
       2014-11-30     44168
       2014-12-31     45518
       2015-01-31     54782
       2015-02-28     52166
       2015-03-31     47929
4      2014-07-31      3147
       2014-08-31     24810
       2014-09-30     39075
       2014-10-31     46857
       2014-11-30     42651
       2014-12-31     48282
       2015-01-31     42708
       2015-02-28     43904
       2015-03-31     50033
```

From here, how can I access different components of this multiIndex object to create a bar plot for the following conditions?

- show data when AXLES = 3
- show x ticks in the Month - Year format (no days, hours, minutes etc.)

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Following code gives me the plot, but I could not change the xtick formatting to MM-YY.

```
resamp[3].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

**EDIT 2** below is a code snippet that generates a small sample of the data similar to what I have:

```
dftest = {'TIMESTAMP':['2014-08-31','2014-09-30','2014-10-31'], 'AXLES':[3, 3, 3], 'CLASS':[5,6,7]}
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(dftest)
dfTest.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dfTest.TIMESTAMP))
resamp = dfTest.set_index('TIMESTAMP').groupby('AXLES').resample('M', how='count').CLASS
resamp[3].plot(kind='bar')
```

**EDIT 3:**
Here below is the solution:

A.Plot the whole resampled dataframe (based on @Ako 's suggestion):

```
df = resamp.unstack(0)
df.index = [ts.strftime('%b 20%y') for ts in df.index]
df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

[image]

B.Plot an individual index from the resampled dataframe (based on @Alexander 's suggestion):

```
df = resamp[3]
df.index = [ts.strftime('%b 20%y') for ts in df.index]
df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `resamp.unstack(0).plot(kind='bar')`. That turns axles to series plotted separately.

Comment: Thanks. That comes handy when showing all data in one plot. Is there a way to change the format of xtick labels from `2015-03-31 00:00:00` to `March 2015`. No matter what I tried I could not change the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, but it is difficult to test without some data.

Start by resetting your index to get access to the `TIMESTAMP` column.  Then use `strftime` to format it to your desired text representation (e.g. mm-yy). Finally, reset the index back to `AXLES` and `TIMESTAMP`.

```
df = resamp.reset_index()
df['TIMESTAMP'] = [ts.strftime('%m-%y') for ts in df.TIMESTAMP]
df.set_index(['AXLES', 'TIMESTAMP'], inplace=True)
>>> df.xs(3, level=0).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could generate and set the labels explicitly using `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` with a `ticker.FixedFormatter`. This will allow you to keep your DataFrame's MultiIndex with timestamp values, while *displaying* the timestamps in the desired `%m-%Y` format:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

dftest = {'TIMESTAMP':['2014-08-31','2014-09-30','2014-10-31'], 'AXLES':[3, 3, 3], 'CLASS':[5,6,7]}
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(dftest)
dfTest.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dfTest.TIMESTAMP))
resamp = dfTest.set_index('TIMESTAMP').groupby('AXLES').resample('M', how='count').CLASS

ax = resamp[3].plot(kind='bar')
ticklabels = [timestamp.strftime('%m-%Y') for axle, timestamp in resamp.index]
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: ticklabels[int(x)]))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

yields
[image]